# Angular routeProvider and passing scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I am using routeProvider to create deep linking in my app. My issue is I need to have multiple levels. So lets say i have a products page the link would be:

http://example.com/#/products

$scope.products contains all of the products.  Once clicked on the product, I need to be able to keep $scope.products and change the URL to http://example.com/#/products/1. the '/1' being the id of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your products controller create a function and call it to navigate to the edit page http://example.com/#/products something like this...

```
$scope.edit = function (data) {
        $window.location.href = '#/Products/Edit' + '?id=' + data.id;
    };
```

on your edit controller call $routeParams and load the object from your api, as it might have changed

```
function loadProduct()
    {
        productEditFactory.getProduct($routeParams.id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response.data;
        }, function (response) {

        });
    }

    if ($routeParams.id)
    {
        loadProduct();
    }
    else {
        $scope.editMode = false;
    }
```

you also need to update your $routeProvider definition with something like this...

```
.when('/Product/Edit', {
        templateUrl: function (params) { return 'Products/Edit?id=' + params.id ; }
    })
```

Comment: But the problem with this is that it doesn't keep the $scope.products

Comment: you can use $rootScope to keep the array as the normal $scope will be wiped out between navigation